# How to properly align the right edges of two views?

Tags: android, android-layout

Here is a simplified version of my problem. I need to align the right edges of two text views such that they appear as follows:

```
        a
 abcdefgh
```

Here is my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    >

   <TextView
      android:id="@+id/tvFirst"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="a"
    /> 

   <TextView
      android:id="@+id/tvSecond"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/tvFirst"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/tvFirst"
    android:text="abcdefgh"
    /> 

</RelativeLayout>
```

Although "a" and "h" do get aligned, the problem is that the width of the layout is that of tvFirst and not of the longer text. As a result, I don't see complete text for tvSecond.

I would appreciate it if you can tell me what is it that I am missing. Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

GridLayout, along with gravity, did the trick:

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvFirst"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="a"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSecond"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="abcdefgh"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="0"
        />
</GridLayout>
```

Regards,
Peter

Answer (score 0):

Wrap them both in `LinearLayout` and give the textviews `android:textAlignment="viewEnd"` attribute:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/tvFirst"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="viewEnd" />

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/tvSecond"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="viewEnd" />              

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This is close except that I cannot do layout_alignParentRight. The topmost RelativeLayout width is set to "wrap_content." This does not go well with layout_alignParentRight. It streches the whole thing to make it look like match_parent.

Comment: OK, I did something like that in another app some other way. Check my new answer.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't add `gravity` to them! Add these attributes to both the TextViews and you will get it:

```
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:gravity="right"
```

Comment: That is not what he wants, though. He did not seem to want to align all the text to the right of the parent. It looks like he just wants to have two text view, the longer align to the left of the parent, the shorter align with the right of the longer one.

Comment: Vishnu. Thanks for your help. However, match_parent doesn't work for me. It has to be wrap_content.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this..




<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    >

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/tvFirst"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
       android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
       android:text="a" />

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/tvSecond"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvFirst"
       android:layout_below="@+id/tvFirst"
       android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
       android:text="abcdefgh" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: As you have used relative layout so tvFist will be parallel at the start of tvSecond or at the end as maintaining the relation to each other..

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the widest one first to anchor things, even though it's below the first, so this will do it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSecond"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvFirst"
        android:text="abcdefgh" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvFirst"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/tvSecond"
        android:text="a" />

</RelativeLayout>
```